# Succinct code format when coercing data types in Haskell

Tags: haskell

As a raw beginner in Haskell I am attempting to get all my exercise code to compile without warning while using the -Wall option in the ghc compiler. I am also trying to understand the use of '$' and '.' to avoid excessive parentheses.

In the following code

```
module Helpers (intSqrt1, intSqrt2)  where 

intSqrt1 :: Int -> Int
intSqrt1 x = truncate $ sqrt $ fromIntegral x

intSqrt2 :: Int -> Int
intSqrt2 x = truncate ( sqrt (fromIntegral x) :: Double)
```

intSqrt1 gives the warning *Defaulting the following constraints to type `Double'*. I can suppress the warning by coercing the result from sqrt to Double (see intSqrt2), but only at the cost of adding two pairs of parentheses.

Is there a way to get the best of both worlds in this function: i.e. both succinct code and suppression of warnings?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that warning and can't immediately see what's causing it, but from a point of view of succinct code, the most idiomatic way to write the function (imo) is simply `intSqrt = truncate . sqrt . fromIntegral`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's happening here is that you're using `fromIntegral` to convert an `Int` to some type `a`, you're using `sqrt` to convert `a` to `a`, and you're using `truncate` to convert `a` back to `Int`. From the constraints on those functions, GHC knows that `a` must be `Floating` and `RealFrac`, but it **doesn't know what `a` is**. To solve this, GHC maintains a set of *defaulting rules*; in this case, they state that any ambiguous type which is `Floating` or `RealFrac` is defaulted to `Double`. Defaulting may not be the intended behaviour in all cases though, so GHC also prints a warning.

When you add the type signature, the ambiguity is removed, which is why the message disappears. Adding a type signature is a bit clunky though; is there a better way? Actually, there is! First, you need to enable the `TypeApplications` extension by putting the following pragma at the top of your file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
```

This extension enables you to use the syntax `@SomeType` as the first parameter of any function; if the function has any type variables in its signature, this *specialises* the first to `SomeType`. (Subsequent uses specialise the second, third, fourth etc. type variable.) In this case, we have a choice of places to put the type application. We could put it on `fromIntegral`:

```hs
intSqrt x = truncate $ sqrt $ fromIntegral @_ @Double x
```

(Note that `fromIntegral` has two type variables, so we leave the first one to be inferred as `Int` and only specialise the second one.)

Or we can put it on `sqrt`:

```hs
intSqrt x = truncate $ sqrt @Double $ fromIntegral x
```

Or on `truncate`:

```hs
intSqrt x = truncate @Double $ sqrt $ fromIntegral x
```

Any of these variants will solve the problem concisely.